# Translations reflect after click on combo, where combo options are filled dynamically in ngOnInit in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an autocomplete drop-down to which I bind list of ViewOption (my class)

```
class ViewOption {
name: string;
ordinal: number;
label: string
}
```

I create list of viewoption in ngOnInit by calling getViewOptionList,

```
getViewOptionList(): ViewOptions {
    const viewoptions = new ViewOptions();

    for (const enumMember in ViewOptionEnum) {
      if (ViewOptionEnum.hasOwnProperty(enumMember)) {

        const viewoption = new ViewOption();
        const ordinalValue = parseInt(enumMember, 10);

        if (ordinalValue >= 0) {
          viewoption.oridinal = ordinalValue;
          viewoption.label = ViewOptionEnum[enumMember].toLowerCase();
          this.translate.get(viewoption.label).subscribe(msg => viewoption.name = msg);
          viewoptions.push(viewoption);
        }
      }
    }

    return viewoptions;
  }

<lis-auto-complete-dropdown placeholder="select view" automationid="worklistMaster_ddl_selectView"
                    [options]="ViewOptions" [(selectedItem)]="selectedViewOption"
                    (itemSelected)="selectViewOption($event)">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
       <span title="{{ item }}">
            <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
       </span>
    </ng-template>
</lis-auto-complete-dropdown>
```

Translation reflect only when user clicks on autocomple dropdown on UI. How to make it fill before user taking any action?

Comment: Can u use $translate.instant(); ?

Comment: translate.instant give translation keys back. that doesn't translate

Comment: refer this then - https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1781 hope it helps!

Comment: translate.refresh doesn't exist in angular 2 onwards,  it was in angular js